# Load of grey in site design

Tags: discussion, design

When reading a question, I noticed an amount of grey on the page. At first I thought it was my monitor playing up but it moved as I scrolled.

Should the colour change be present?

[image: Image showing problem]

(dotted lines present for easier ability to see the change)

Comment: There's a sort-of gradient in the background design; but that still has colour - yours seems to be sick, have you tried ctrl+f5?

Comment: I have tried reloading and it's still there. I can't find where the images are being loaded from though

Comment: are you behind any special firewall?

Comment: I am not behind a special firewall. I can visit the rest of the network completely normally

Comment: The white part of the page is slightly transparent. What you're seeing is probably the background image bleeding thorugh.

Comment: It fixes itself when I go fullscreen though. I think I'm seeing the robot bleed through

Comment: Try running $(content).css("background-color", "rgba(255,255,255,0.25)") in the browser console, that should make the white part more transparent so you can see what's underneath. Transparency is normally set to 0.95

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh By running that, the visibility of the bleed gets greater as the transparency of the white goes down

Comment: @muddyfish right, so you can better see the source of the grey.You should also be able to run $(content).css("background-color", "rgba(255,255,255,1)") to remove the grey part entirely.